# Resizing two Images on upload in Django

Tags: python, django, upload, resize

I wanna make a form with two images, the first is a resize of the original photo, and the second one is the thumbnail, i want to save the image in two different directories, this is what i'm doing but i can´t save the thumbnail.

models.py

```
class Cakes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    descrip = models.TextField(verbose_name='Descripction')
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='Cake', verbose_name='Imagen')
    imagen2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='Cake/thumbnail', verbose_name='Imagen2')
    time_regist = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

view.py

```
def new_cake(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = CakesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            resize_imagen(request.FILES['imagen'],250)

            resize_imagen(request.FILES['imagen'],960)

            formulario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/paneladmin')
    else:
        formulario = CakesForm()
    return render_to_response('nuevocake.html', {'formulario': formulario}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def resize_imagen(img, size):
    import StringIO, os
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps
    from django.core.files import File
    imagenarchivo = StringIO.StringIO(img.read())
    imagenImagen = Image.open(imagenarchivo)
    if size == 250:
        imagenImagen.thumbnail((250,120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else:
        imagenImagen.thumbnail((960,720), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # re-initialize imageFile

    imagefile = StringIO.StringIO()
    imagenImagen.save(imagefile,'JPEG')
```

I don't want the original imagen because the original files are to heavy and that's why i'm trying to make a resize. And the function resize_imagen does not work.

Comment: Are you getting a message? What in particular isn't working in the routine?

Comment: I'm getting this error 'cannot identify image file <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x03220198>'

Comment: @urdaneta88 can you show us the full traceback? With line is that error message pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a utility function I use, `save_thumbnail`. I recommend placing it in `app_name/utils.py`

This has the added capability of fetching the original image from the database (extra query...) to confirm that the image has changed before updating thumbnail image to save on PIL processing.

*(If you pass `force_thumbnail` it will always create thumbnail without fetching original image to see if it has changed since last save.)*

```
# models.py
from django.db import transaction
import app_name.utils

class Node(models.Model):
    # ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='node_images', null=False)
    thumbnail_200w = models.ImageField(upload_to='node_images/200w', null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            # instance_class, self, image_attr, thumbnail_attr, width, height=None
            cms.utils.save_thumbnail(Node, self, 'image', 'thumbnail_200w', 200, None)
            super(Node, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
# utils.py
from PIL import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
import os

def save_thumbnail(instance_class, instance, image_attr, thumbnail_attr, max_width, max_height=None, force_thumbnail=False):
    new_image = getattr(instance, image_attr)
    if not new_image:
        return

    if not force_thumbnail:
        if instance.id:
            existing_image = getattr(instance_class.objects.get(id=instance.id), image_attr)
        else:
            existing_image = None

        if new_image == existing_image:
            return  # exit because the file hasn't changed, no need to generate thumbs

    super(instance_class, instance).save()

    thumbnail = create_thumbnail(getattr(instance, image_attr).file, max_width, max_height)
    getattr(instance, thumbnail_attr).save(thumbnail.name, thumbnail, save=False)


def create_thumbnail(original, max_width, max_height=None):

    # Open original photo which we want to thumbnail using PIL's Image
    image = Image.open(StringIO(original.read()))

    # Set our max thumbnail size in a tuple (max width, max height)
    if max_height:
        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (max_width, max_height)
        image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else:
        # scale to width, keeping aspect
        width_ratio = (max_width/float(image.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(width_ratio)))
        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (max_width, hsize)
        image = image.resize(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    DJANGO_TYPE = original.file.content_type

    if DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/jpeg':
     PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
     FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
    elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/png':
     PIL_TYPE = 'png'
     FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'
    elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/gif':
     PIL_TYPE = 'gif'
     FILE_EXTENSION = 'gif'


    # Save the thumbnail
    temp_handle = StringIO()
    image.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
    temp_handle.seek(0)

    # Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into ImageField
    return SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(original.name)[-1],
         temp_handle.read(), content_type=DJANGO_TYPE)
```